# Spread input of number

Tags: java

input : 1234 | output : 1 2 3 4

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = reader.nextInt();
```

How can I spread input to output?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Is your output supposed to be a `String` or four `int`s?

Comment: Just place this at the bottom of your exiting code: `System.out.println(String.valueOf(num).replaceAll("(\\d)", "$1 ").trim());`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Take the input as a string
2. Split the string by character with the regex `"(?!^)"`
3. Join the array as a string with a space as delimiter

See below the solution and output:

Solution:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print ("Enter a number: ");
String input = reader.next();
String[] nums = input.split("(?!^)");
String myString = String.join(" ", nums);
System.out.print (myString);
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 1234
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Elegant solution by the way.

Comment: Thank you, I like when it is well sanitized ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following code to print every char one by one.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String number = scanner.next();
for(char c: number.toCharArray()) {
   System.out.print(c+" ");
}
```

**Update**

If not printing a blank space in the end is important to the solution, the following code would accomplish the goal.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String number = scanner.next();
for(int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++){
    if(i == number.length()-1){
        System.out.print(number.charAt(i));
    } else {
        System.out.print(number.charAt(i) + " ");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This won’t print with spaces in between the numbers, right?

Comment: Nope, let me change it, thought he only wanted the numbers printed.

Comment: The requirement is `1 2 3 4` not `1 2 3 4 ` with an extra space I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try and do this

```
System.out.println(input.replace("", " ").trim());
```

Where input is the string that you get from scanner like so,

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print ("Enter a number: ");
String input = reader.next();
```

Replace will replace all empty substrings with spaces and trim will remove extra spaces at the start and finish

Comment: @JonathanGagne, it works for me. I tried here https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler ... try this String s = "1234"; System.out.println(s.replace("", " ").trim());

Comment: True, I did `String input = reader.next();`, `input.replace("", " ").trim();` and `System.out.println(input)` my bad ^^

Comment: I don't hate it! Your solution is providing the right output as well. +1

Comment: @JonathanGagne, thanks a lot! :D +1 to you too :)